# tomcat virtual host jsp works, faces do not work

Tags: jsf, tomcat

```
in my tomcat virtual host configuration, while jsp work fine, without port number on URL, faces do not work without port number.
ortipisani.it_slash_old_slash_test2.jsp is ok but
ortipisani.it:8080_slash_faces_slash_home.xhtml is ok but
ortipisani.it_slash_faces_slash_home.xhtml do not work
```

I have setting my virtual host in httpd.conf, in server.conf of tomcat configuration files, and in web.xml configuration file. 
But today I cant get a good configuration.

my web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

my virtual host in httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@ortipisani.it
    DocumentRoot /home/ortipisani/www/html
    ServerName ortipisani.it
    ServerAlias www.ortipisani.it
    ErrorLog /home/ortipisani/www/error_log
    CustomLog /home/ortipisani/www/access_log combined
    JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
    </VirtualHost>
```

my virtual host in server.xml (tomcat conf):

```
    <Host 
        name="ortipisani.it">
        appBase="/home/ortipisani/www/html/"
        unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false"
        xmlValidation="false" 
        xmlNamespaceAware="false"
        >
        <Alias>www.ortipisani.it</Alias>
    </Host>
```

I have tried with meny types of settings, but I cant get a good configuration.
What have I to do?
Thanks

UPDATE
Today I have put

```
JKMount /*.xhtml ajp13
JKMount /faces/* ajp13
```

into my virtual host setting in httpd.conf.
From

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@ortipisani.it
DocumentRoot /home/ortipisani/www/html
ServerName ortipisani.it
ServerAlias www.ortipisani.it
ErrorLog /home/ortipisani/www/error_log
CustomLog /home/ortipisani/www/access_log combined
JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@ortipisani.it
DocumentRoot /home/ortipisani/www/html
ServerName ortipisani.it
ServerAlias www.ortipisani.it
ErrorLog /home/ortipisani/www/error_log
CustomLog /home/ortipisani/www/access_log combined
JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
JKMount /*.xhtml ajp13
JKMount /faces/* ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it work fine.